# Can XSD restriction be platform specific?

Tags: c++, c, xml, xsd, schema

I have to specify a restriction for one of xml attribute, I know I can use the syntax below.

---

But the minInclusive and MaxInclusive depends on platform. How do I specify such syntax? Are they supported in XSD?

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: My xsd currently looks like below. I need to change min and max values as per platform






<xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedInt">
               <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
               <xsd:maxInclusive value="15"/>
         </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

Comment: Well, you could do something like `<xsd:minInclusive value="&platformMin;"/> <xsd:maxInclusive value="&platformMax;"/>` and arrange for `platformMin` and `platformMax` to be defined to your taste via an external entity. Then make sure the right entity is used on each platform.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I need to publish this schema as a reference. It cannot accept any values, and moreover I need to specify the min and max values for many platforms (each platform has a different values for min and max) like 1 .. 5 for X86 and 10 .. 100 for PPC etc.

I wanted to specify this information in xsd:appinfo, but looking for other better options

Comment: In what way does my suggestion contradict this goal? If push comes to shove, have an internal DTD at the top of the file that defines multiple versions of `platformMin` and `platformMax`, one for each platform, all commented out. Provide the instruction, again in the comments, to uncomment the set of definitions corresponding to the user's platform.

Answer (score 0):

Saxon's XSD processor introduces the idea of validation parameters, which you can specify when invoking the schema processor from the command line or from an application - you can't use them in facets like minInclusive and maxInclusive, but you can use them in xs:assert and other places where XPath expressions are used.

It's good to see that this meets a real requirement, though to be honest, until such a feature becomes widely implemented in other processors it would be a little unwise to base your strategy on it.